# basic (lightweight) lightbox plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello i am looking for a very basic (lightweight) jquery lightbox solution that i can show my pictures and vimeo videos (flash player) on it. and of course browser friendly. I tried fancybox and its not working good in different browsers and also has some bugs on flash medias.

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend this script, it is very simple and is responsive:
-----------------
[http://vilsoni.info/demo/?i=ilb](http://vilsoni.info/demo/?i=ilb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need flash, you might want to inspect this here [matrix of lightbox clones](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/). It suggests that [FancyZoom](http://orderedlist.com/articles/fancyzoom-meet-jquery) might do the trick.

This [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) clone for jQuery is good, you might retrofit it to your needs.

Comment: it doesnt works with flash media i think. i need to show my flash movies also.

Comment: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ shows a 504 Error

and http://orderedlist.com/articles/fancyzoom-meet-jquery shows a 404 Error